Martial arts movie where man shoots darts/arrows out of stringed instrument?
I saw this movie in the last 20-25 years - for some reason I think it was released in the 90s in the US (possibly early 2000s), but I'm not certain. Anyway, it's a martial arts movie based in China that as I recall had a good bit of comedy in it as well. A bunch of people live in a large building/neighborhood with a courtyard in the middle, and a bad man/men comes to town that they're trying to get rid of. There's a woman in the complex with a deadly scream, and when she opens her shutters everyone scuttles away. The most memorable part is a man who plays a Chinese stringed instrument that lays horizontally across his lap, and when he strums the strings all these darts/arrows appear from them and fly towards his target. It may be a guzheng (古箏) or more likely a guqin (古琴), but I'm no expert.
I get the feeling that Quentin Tarantino was involved in some way, but that may not be correct (and why I'm not tagging this as such). The production values and visual FX were quite good, quite the opposite of something like Drunken Master. I don't believe it was dubbed, either. I remember really enjoying the movie when I saw it, and I just can't for the life of me remember what it was called. If anyone has any leads I'd be extremely grateful.

You're after the hilarious Kung Fu Hustle from 2004:

Set in Canton, China in the 1940s, the story revolves in a town ruled by the Axe Gang [and] Sing who desperately wants to become a member. He stumbles into a slum ruled by eccentric landlords who turn out to be the greatest kung-fu masters in disguise. Sing's actions eventually cause the Axe Gang and the slumlords to engage in an explosive kung-fu battle. Only one side will win and only one hero will emerge as the greatest kung-fu master of all. 

Everything you've described is there. Here's the trailer:




You are awesome. Here, have an upvote :)

TBH I'm surprised this went unanswered for a full half hour. Such a fun movie.

Well, I did post it late on a Saturday night. Even Stack Overflow is dead then.
